# How can I make MdiChild forms be in tabs in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, tabs, mdichild, mdiparent

I have a MDIparent Forma and which has some mdichild forms in it. Can you help me some how put the mdichilds in Tabs like google chrome , firefox , IE , Opera ...

Comment: Hey did you find a good reference for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a good article on MDI forms with TabControls here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/MDITabBrowsing.aspx

Comment: ThankYou , I had seen it but I need close button for each tab something like Google Chrome but much simpler

Comment: this is flickering when changing tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
myForm.TopLevel=false;
myForm.TopMost=false;
tabPage1.Controls.Add(myForm);
```